# WPF Как проверить выбранный CheckBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

Есть таблица, в столбце *Статус заявки* находятся CheckkBox'ы.
Вывод данных в эту таблицу идет из БД.

```
 <ListView x:Name="userList" Margin="10,73,10,58">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="№" Width="30" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding numReq}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Название" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding shortDesc}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Описание" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding longDesc}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ФИО" Width="400" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fioUser}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Статус заявки" Width="400">

                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding statusReq}" IsEnabled="{Binding enableCheck}" Click="checkBox" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Я пытался заново перебрать всю таблицу, чтобы определить номер строки (id), на которой CheckBox стал активным. Также поставил фильтр(первая конструкция if) на те CheckBox'ы, которые уже выведены из БД, то есть true и являются неактивными, так как у пользователя нет возможности изменять уже включенные CheckBox'ы.

```
private void checkBox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        DataTable req_out = specWindow.Select("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Request]");
        for (int j = 0; j < req_out.Rows.Count; j++)
        { // перебираем данные
            active_table = ("" + req_out.Rows[j][4]);
            if(active_table=="0")
            {
                if (statusReq)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Отмечен столбец № " + j);
                }
            }
        }
```

Реализация класса коллекции

```
 public class monitorReq
{
    public string numReq { get; set; }
    public string fioUser { get; set; }
    public string department { get; set; }
    public string cabinet { get; set; }
    public string numPc { get; set; }
    public string shortDesc { get; set; }
    public string longDesc { get; set; }
    public bool statusReq { get; set; }
    public bool enableCheck { get; set; }

    public monitorReq(string _numReq, string _fioUser, string _department, string _cabinet, string _numPc, string _shortDesc, string _longDesc, bool _statusReq, bool _enableCheck)
    {
        this.numReq = _numReq;
        this.fioUser = _fioUser;
        this.department = _department;
        this.cabinet = _cabinet;
        this.numPc = _numPc;
        this.shortDesc = _shortDesc;
        this.longDesc = _longDesc;
        this.statusReq = _statusReq;
        this.enableCheck = _enableCheck;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как определить строку(по сути id), в которой пользователь только что отметил checkbox, чтобы можно было записать это в переменную и отправить в БД?
Вот скрин таблицы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем искать перебором? Разве сам sender не нужный вам checkbox?

Comment: Вообще да, `sender` - это и есть тот самый чекбокс. Можно по визуальному дереву найти строку и данные в ней. Но лучше воспользоваться ответом, который я дал ниже. :)

Comment: Попробуйте изменить политику именования переменных: свойства с большой буквы, поля с маленькой и с подчеркиванием, локальные переменные просто с маленькой.

Comment: @aepot вы читаете мои мысли) Увидел у вас, что переменные начинаются с большой буквы, да и сам VS выдает сообщения, что неправильное наименование. Буду исправляться!

Comment: @AnatolyWPF и можно без конструктора обойтись, свойства позволяют ограничить доступ, например только `{ get; }` возволяет изменить свойство только при создании класса, `{ get; private set; }` позволяет дополнительно менять свойство внутри класса, ну и `{ get; set; }` - полный доступ. Ну можно еще то же самое наоборот, с ограничением записи. Как создать клас со свойствами и без конструктора, я показал в ответе.

Comment: @aepot я создал классы по вашему примеру. Класс NotifyPropertyChanged, класс UserItem и класс MainViewModel. Далее разместил в основном окне эти строки `MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();`.
    `DataContext = vm;` Но вот с коллекцией разобраться не могу

Comment: @aepot я добавил в тему реализацию списка. Я пытаюсь заменить список как раз таки `ObservableCollection`. Но он выдает, что UserList не существует в текущем контексте. Насколько я понял он должен ее брать из класса MainViewModel или мне также как и `List` нужно создать его в основном окне?

Comment: Намекаю, `ObservableCollection<monitorReq> monitorreq` и классы тоже бы с большой буквы :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы боретесь с контролами, и при этом не используете встроенные возможности WPF. Обратите внимание на шаблон программирования [MVVM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern).

Я покажу короткий пример на базе этого шаблона.

Потребуется вспомогательный класс для реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged` интерфейса. Суть его заключается в том, чтобы уведомлять UI о любых изменениях просто изменяя данные.

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Затем потребуется класс с данными, и сразу сделаю его так, чтобы он уведомлял интерфейс об изменениях. Другими словами, если вы внесете изменения в `DataGrid`, они сразу поменяются в данных, и наоборот. Вам не придется больше взаимодействовать с `DataGrid`, а только с данными.

```cs
public class UserItem : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _numReq;
    private string _shortDesc;
    private string _longDesc;
    private string _fioUser;
    private bool _statusReq;

    public int NumReq
    {
        get => _numReq;
        set
        {
            _numReq = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // уведомляет UI об изменении
        }
    }
    public string ShortDesc
    {
        get => _shortDesc;
        set
        {
            _shortDesc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string LongDesc
    {
        get => _longDesc;
        set
        {
            _longDesc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string FioUser
    {
        get => _fioUser;
        set
        {
            _fioUser = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool StatusReq
    {
        get => _statusReq;
        set
        {
            // сюда попадаем как только изменен чекбокс
            // при этом не важно, програмно или из UI
            // можно прямо отсюда кинуть запрос в БД, все нужные данные в прямой видимости
            _statusReq = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Затем, основной класс для `MainWindow`, который будет содержать все свойства, к которыйм в свою очередь будут привязаны зависимые свойства контролов интерфейса в помощью `Binding`.

```cs
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<UserItem> _userList;

    public ObservableCollection<UserItem> UserList // коллекция, к которой привязана DataGrid
    {
        get => _userList;
        set
        {
            _userList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        UserList = new ObservableCollection<UserItem>();

    }
}
```

А чтобы интерфейс узнал, в каком классе все свойства, куда будут привязываться все биндинги, нужно задать `DataContext` у окна

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

Чтобы работали подсказки к биндингам в разметке, в параметрах Window в XAML можно указать `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainViewModel}"`.

Ну и сама разметка таблицы

```xaml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" Margin="10,73,10,58">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="№" Width="30" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NumReq}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Название" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShortDesc}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Описание" Width="*" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LongDesc}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ФИО" Width="400" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FioUser}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Статус заявки" Width="400">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding StatusReq, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <!-- UpdateSourceTrigger перезаписывает свойство сразу как юзер на него нажмет -->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Работать с `ObservableCollection` можно точно так же как с уже знакомым вам `List`. Она отличается от `List` в основном тем, что внутри нее вызывается событие `CollectionChanged` при добавлении или удалнии элементов коллекции, а на него автоматически подписывается `DataGrid`.

```csharp
UserList.Add(new UserItem() { NumReq = 1, FioUser = "Семён Семёнович", ShortDesc = "Монитор", LongDesc = "Выключился", StatusReq = false });
```

Про загрузку данных, просто грузите их не в `DataGrid`, а в коллекцию.

*Если решитесь попробовать MVVM, есть еще команды, к ним можно биндить кнопки, меню и прочие контролы, в которых не меняются зависимые свойства, а просто надо что-то сделать, когда что-то нажато. Я не буду добавлять примеры использования команд в этот ответ, но их можно найти в других моих ответах StackOverflow, у меня в профиле.*

Примеры

```csharp
private ObservableCollection<MonitorReq> _monitorReqList = new ObservableCollection<MonitorReq>();

public ObservableCollection<MonitorReq> MonitorReqList // я бы так назвал
{
    get => _monitorReqList;
    set
    {
        _monitorReqList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

```csharp
public class MonitorReq : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // реализация класса данных
}
```

Comment: Ух, INPC во все возможные щели добавили, он же в этом примере вообще не нужен) Например, зачем он у `ObservableCollection<UserItem> UserList`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ откуда вы знаете, что нужно автору, а что не нужно? :) Я думаю, проще оптимизировать, чем реализовать. Просто показал, как можно, а уж как нужно, пусть решает автор.

Comment: Просто потом, автор это возьмет за эталон и без разбирательств начнет вызывать INPC по каждому чиху (не раз такое видел), увы, люди не хотят думать и разбираться, особенно новички. Так что если уж и добавили INPC, то напишите когда его стоит использовать и дайте этому пример, иначе мы с вами будет разгребать тонну кода, состоящего из сплошных `OnPropertyChanged();`. Сейчас лично я (будь на месте новичка), читая данный ответ думаю, что по MVVM правилам, каждое свойство должно выглядеть так (с переписанным `get` и `set`, да еще и с `OnPropertyChanged();`), тем более написано `Потребуется класс`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я думал, что на работу берут тех, что понимает, что пишет. Тем более, MVVM в WPF - это очень простая штука, ну в сравнении с Winforms во всяком случае. И я детально написал, зачем нужен INPC, и в частности `OnPropertyChanged()`. У меня нет цели разжевывать каждую букву в коде. Если же считаете, что это необходимо - прошу, можете отредактировать и дополнить мой ответ, я только за. Спасибо за дельное замечание, но это не баг, а фича. :)

Comment: @aepot спасибо Вам за ваш ответ! Он очень содержательный) Вы написали, что можно при изменении вставить запрос  тогда все запишется. Но как мне обратиться именно к тому ID, в котором поменяли этот самый чекбокс. Извините за возможную бестактность - я новичок!)

Comment: @AnatolyWPF `NumReq` - не оно? `MessageBox.Show(NumReq.ToString())` или (чтобы меня тут не побили знающие люди) `Debug.WriteLine(NumReq)`. Класс по сути представляет собой строку таблицы.

Comment: @aepot, смотрите, а если у меня уже есть класс, через который проходят все эти переменные. То есть я присваиваю через цикл переменным значения из бд и они проходят через класс.  `monitorreq.Add(new monitorReq(numRequest, fioUserReq, Depart_table, Cab_table, numPcUser, shortDescReq, longDescReq, statusReq, enableCheck));` Там он присваиваются как раз тем переменным, которые выводятся в binding. То есть коллекцию я уже реализовал. Нужно ли мне создавать еще один класс или можно исправить этот?

Comment: @AnatolyWPF не нужно, можно переделать существующий, и заменить List на ObservableCollection.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать)

Comment: @AnatolyWPF код лучше редактированием в вопрос добавлять. Создайте тестовое приложение, внесите туда код, который я вам показал, попробуйте понять, как он работает.

Comment: @AnatolyWPF добавил в ответ примеры реализации.

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое, все работает, оказывается нужно было просто поспать)